Equivalence of cohomology with compact support
Let $$ be a connected CW complex, $:\pi_1()→\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ a representation, and $G_\rho$ the associated sheaf. It follows from here, that the following two cohomologies are isomorphic.
(1)The cohomology of the complex $_{\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]}(C_i\tilde{X},G)$, where $\tilde{X}$ is the universal cover of $X$, and $C_i\tilde{X}$ is the $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]$-module of -dimensional cells in $\tilde{X}$.
(2)The sheaf cohomology of $G_\rho$.
What is the corresponding (1) for sheaf cohomology with compact support of $G_\rho$?

Inside $Hom_{\pi_1}(C_\ast \tilde X,G)$ there is a subcomplex of all cochains $\phi$ such that there exists a finite collection $C$ of cells of $X$ with the property that $\phi=0$ on all cells except those that project to elements of $C$. It seems plausible that this complex calculates $H^*c(X,G\varrho)$.
